# Is it possible to restrict admin (Django Administration) not to access to Users' private information (Journal entries) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am currently developing a journal application with Django. As the journal entries would be a private thing. Is it possible to restrict admin not to access the Journal information?

I have tried to add some codes in the `admin.py`, put it doesn't work.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Journal

class JournalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(user=request.user)

admin.site.register(Journal, JournalAdmin)
```

This code as well.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Journal

class JournalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.user != request.user:
            return False
        return True

admin.site.register(Journal,JournalAdmin)
```

Comment: encrypt the entries  ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes. I want to encrypt the entries

Comment: so when user journal is saved in the db then ffor that entries encrypt the data first

Comment: Isn't it an option for you to just not register `Journal` to admin? Or do you just want to hide one specific field of `Journal` from admin?

Comment: Just remove the `if` from the `get_queryset` and leave only the `else` part?

Comment: @Tarquinius oh yeah. I forgot that I can choose to not register it.